Sweet Alert 2 js library with Interop from blazor server
I have a blazor server app in which I want to use sweetalert2 methods, I want to do it using js interop , not by nuget sweetalert package. Below is my code
App.razor
<body>
<Routes @rendermode=RenderMode.InteractiveServer />
<script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

included sweetalert2.all.min.js before _framework/blazor.web.js
And in c# code on a function click
 private void CallJs()
{
    Js.InvokeVoidAsync("Swal.fire", args: "Some message to display");
}

This should invoke simplest sweet alert form as below
Swal.fire("SweetAlert2 is working!");

But above is not working
I tried with another file with normal alert as
   function sayHello(name) {
    alert(`Hello ${name}`);
}

and in c#
 private void CallJs()
 {
     Js.InvokeVoidAsync("sayHello", args: "Bob");
 }

and above works , but when use js interop with a library like sweetalert, bootstrap .... it does not work, how to call properly sweetlaert methods here ?
I am using .net 8.0

Web reference works
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.11.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.11.0/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Home.razor
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime js
@* put this script reference to App.razor also works *@
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.11.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<button @onclick="test">test</button>
@code{
    private async Task test(){
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("Swal.fire", args: "Some message to display");
    }
}

Test


Can you share your js interop code with this ?

@Saurabh I used async method, but your code using void CallJs without async await also works. I post it in the answer
